# How to insert datetime like this format 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I want to insert my DateTime into SQL Server like 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'.

Generally, I have formed the below query to insert that DateTime in SQL.

```
insert into tablename values(convert(date,'10/02/2012',110))
```

It inserts like this `"2012-10-02"` but I don't know why it inserts like this?

I am new to SQL Server.

Is this possible way to store like this **`'02-10-2016'`** in US format?

Comment: Dates are always stored in an internal numeric value. The formatting to dd/MM/yyyy happens when it is presented to you. You just need to change the default date presentation format of your database.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql

Comment: How can i change default date presentation of the database?

Comment: I have added a link to Microsoft's documentation on my previous post.

Comment: Why can't you just `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')`?

Comment: @KtX2SkD why do this, and have to deal with parsing on the client? Setting the format string for a textbox, report, whatever is very easy

Comment: KtX2SkD,It format also stores same not look like my result

Comment: @prabhu there is no such thing as "presentation" in a database. It's *your client code* that presents the data. What kind of application are you building, in what language and why don't you just set the format you want whenever you need it?

Comment: @prabhu Please explain what you want to do. Most applications can actually detect the end user's format. .NET definitely uses the end user's locale to format dates and numbers. Reports allow you to specify the formatting language or locale for the entire report

Comment: Panagiotis,my need is to just store whatever date looks like then it could be store in datetime in 'en-US'[month/date/year] in SQL Server.

Comment: @prabhu what is the type of the field? Are you sure you aren't mistaking the way your tools display dates for some non-existent internal format?

Comment: @prabhu there is no such thing. Dates have no format. They are binary values. It's your tool, SSMS, or whatever else you are using, that formats dates a certain way.

Comment: @prabhu, 29th of May 2017 is stored in database as 42883. When you query it, it is displayed depending on what your `FORMAT`, `CAST`, or `CONVERT` asks it to be. Without using those, I think it would choose a format defined in some configuration to be the default, which I think *Panagiotis* was mentioning earlier.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok there is no way to store 'dd/MM/yyyy' into SQL Server look like 'MM/dd/yyyy' right?

Comment: @prabhu you completely misunderstood what everyone is saying. There is no way to store *ANY FORMAT* because *THERE ARE NO FORMATS*. What tool are you using? Why do you assume that there is any format involved at all? Go to **your tool** and change its locale or date format string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes okay now i understand that date store in Binary format and it will show default date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

Assuming the date column is `date_column`, you can use `convert` while displaying the `date_column` in various formats. Read the attached reference for various formats.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_column, 110) AS [MM-DD-YYYY] from tablename;
```

EDIT: Corrected the date format from Italian to US as I misread the question earlier.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Comment: There's no reason to hard-code an arbitrary format on the database. It's easier for the client to decide what format to use. In many cases it's automatic, eg when a desktop client uses the user's locale for display, or a web page uses the browser's accepted languages for the same purpose

Comment: I think you just want to say that the date should be converted when reading, not when writing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - OP said that he wanted to display date in a particular format, and that is what it will do. `[MM-DD-YYYY]` is just a column alias.

Comment: No, he said he wants to *store* in a specific format, because he assumes that somehow, dates have formats. Furthermore, if you want to display anything and *NOT* end up with the `6th day of Month 16', you should format dates on the client side. If the OP confuses eg the SSMS date display for some internal format, he is highly likely to try to parse that string with the wrong format too

Comment: Which was already rejected from first comment from  Marc, after which he said `How can i change default date presentation of the database`, hence one way to display it.

Comment: @Utsav, yes it will present it as he wants it, but Panagiotis solution is much better. Leave the dates as dates (you will avoid many problems in the future when dealing with those dates) and just inform the client about the date format that you want to present it. A SET DATEFORMAT dmy; will do on most clients.

Comment: @MarcGuillot that's not what I meant at all. *Don't* perform any formating on the server. Set the client's CultureInfo to `en-US`, or the report's language to `en-US`.

Comment: My thinking is that if date column is stored as `date` (as in this case), whenever you want to display it on a report/UI/csv_file, use the conversion at query level for that particular required output. May be I am not right, but based on scenarios I work on, this is what I think.