# Insert Date and String on table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with the following properties:

```
U. TRADE_ID VARCHAR2
   TRADE_DATE DATE
   PRICE NUMBER(10.2)
```

Once I get the data from a file, the colums are as follow:
PSD231,03051982,50.1

My question is, are those the correct datatypes for the table? I'm getting the input from the file for the first sql column as a String. But I can't display it. I think I'm missing something in the sql part. How can I create a new  sql row filled with data so I can test it? This is what I tried and works:

```
insert into myTable(TRADE_ID, TRADE_DATE, PRICE)
    values('PSD231', date '2011-01-01', 10.4);
```

but I'm trying create a query with the date in the format:
01-01-2011, not like the above

Comment: `PSD231` should be `'PSD231'` (notice the single quotes).

Comment: After the first comma at values, why says date? I think that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras that's mainly what I'm asking, if the format is correct. Like that works tho

Comment: When you insert a string it always go with simple quotes, that applies to dates and datetimes. If you are going to insert numeric values (named int, float, decimal, etc) they don't go between quotes of any kind. So your `'10.4'` should only be `10.4`

Comment: What if I wanted to insert the values like this: 10-06-2019 in the format ddmmyyyy instead of how I have it in the query: 2011-01-01. Because if I try like that it says: `"day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"` @AntonioVenerosoContreras

Comment: Check [this page](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php), it will help you convert string to dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What if I wanted to insert the values like this: 10062019 in the format ddmmyyyy instead of how I have it in the query: 2011-01-01 "

Just put single quotes around the date, '10062019', and make sure it is in the correct date format for your region (ddmmyyyy in your case).

```
insert into myTable (TRADE_ID, TRADE_DATE, PRICE)
values ('PSD231', '20110101', 10.4);
```

To change date formats, use the `CONVERT` function e.g

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 1)
```

There is a nice list for the convert function [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: You are still putting the year in the front of the month and date, from the input file I have this date: `03051982` and I need to insert it

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined the first field as a `varchar` type, it should be more like,

```
insert into myTable(TRADE_ID, TRADE_DATE, PRICE)
    values('PSD231','2011-01-01', '10');
```

Values should be enclosed into single quotes when they are being inserted.

Comment: Alright, so that doesn't solve it but it helps me a lot to debug, I missed that. Thanks

Comment: What if I wanted to insert the values like this: 10062019 in the format ddmmyyyy instead of how I have it in the query: 2011-01-01

Comment: It is not recommended to save a date in that format but if you want to return the value that way you could save it as a string or customize the returned value as per your requirement

Comment: I'm not trying to save it in that format, the String that I have from a text flle is in this format: `PSD231,03051982,50.1` So I need to create a query to insert it, but the query above follows this format: 2011-01-01, not the one on the input File

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240160/how-to-insert-datetime-like-this-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: check this link you might find what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you that's going to help